# Would ripping DVDs for individuals violates the copyright law?

Tags: copyright, copyright-transfer

I have the following scenario:

A friend of mine asked me to rip a few DVDs that he has and he wants me to place the digital asset (video) on the cloud and asked to give him all the rights to play it from mobile phone.  Would such action be considered as copyright violation even if I still posses the physical disks?  What if my friend can play only on one device at a time - is that still a violation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you and your friend are and where the copyright was created.

Ripping music for personal use is considered fair use/fair dealing in most jurisdictions. Having multiple copies/devices for personal use is OK too - practically, you can't watch more than one at a time unless you have a very unusual brain.

If the intention is that both you and he would have and use copies then that is a violation.

Comment: The intent is that my friend will use it and i will not. But I wonder if this is done as a business and some profit extracted in exchange for encodind, storing and streaming the media. Could that be practiced or "labels" and content providers will be after such practices?

Comment: Think about it - if you operated a storage company and charged for storing the guys DVDs; this is not copyright violation. If you operated a cloud storage device and charged for storing the guys DVD data ...

Comment: See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act  and specifically "RealNetworks, Inc. v. DVD Copy Control Association, Inc." part that talks about the ripping the DVDs.